# Applying logic for each of the row in DataFrame in pyspark in distributed way?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working on a application that processes the data using apache-spark.
I have a Spark DataFrame that has id, number of banners ( represented by banner_id ). for each of the id, I have to retrieve the number of banner_ids. Depending on the number of banner_ids, I have 4 usecases ( business logic ) to execute.

For example -

factory.py -

```
def get_usecase(number_of_banners: int, campaign_id: int):
        """Consider X as number of banner_ids then"""
        usecases = [
            (lambda x: x >= 100, scenario1),
            (lambda x: 50 <= x < 100, scenario2)
        ]

        for condition, usecase_cls in usecases:
            if condition(number_of_banners):
                return usecase_cls(number_of_banners, campaign_id)
```

scenario1 and scenario2 are the instances of class Scenario1 and Scenario2 which has execute method that execute queries stored in sql files using sparksql ( need spark_session here ).

from main.py -

```
def process_row(row, spark_session):
    use_case_cls = UseCaseFactory.get_usecase(number_of_banners_with_conversions)
    result_df = use_case_cls.execute(spark_session)


spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[2]") \
                .appName("test application") \
                .config("spark.ui.enabled", "false") \
                .getOrCreate()
base_df = base.get_number_of_banners(spark) # determine X
result_rdd = base_df.rdd.flatMap(lambda row: process_row(row, self.spark))
```

This above line gives an serialisation error - `_pickle.PicklingError: Cannot pickle file <stdin> as it cannot be read`. how do I pass spark_session to each of the scenario1 classes? or is there any other better way to handle this?

Since base_df can have huge data, I want to execute this in distributed way.